# How to compute the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I have a rather large, for a human, symmetric covariance matrix in $\mathbb R^{64\times 64}$.  I want to find its eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors (or rather the largest eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector).

Since my matrix is symmetric, the spectral theorem apply.  However I don't know how to compute the matrix of eigenvectors and the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.  Is there a symbolic way to compute that, or am I forced to go iteratively and numerically with a gradient descent or something ?

**Note**: for those who guessed, I am indeed trying to implement for myself *principal component analysis*, however the sources I find assume I can easily compute the eigenvalues whereas I want to implement their computation as well.

Comment: Have you considered the power method? It converges to the largest eigenvalue and it's corresponding eigenvector. It converges rather quickly if the next biggest eigenvalue is much smaller.

Comment: Since you want to find all eigenvalues I wouldn't use the power method. And since your matrix is symmetric I would use [Lanczos Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) paired with a [QR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm)-Iteration. Both are pretty easy and can be found in most packages.

Comment: You are looking for Singular Value Decomposition and in any language these are implemented. So if you have a computer then you have these solvers.